# Aplicación de solver Cplex en python

Tags: python, optimización

Me gustaría usar este gran solver (Cplex) en python, alguien sabe como debería instalarlo o que debo bajar?. He usado siempre Gurobi con una licencia académica, pero Cplex es gratis y me gustaría aprender a usarlo. Espero sus respuestas, desde ya muchas gracias a todos y saludos. :D

Comment: No tengo experiencia con Cplex, pero [PuLP](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/) es una biblioteca Python que permite usar python como lenguaje de modelado y que después genera la descripción del problema en diferentes lenguajes y para diferentes solvers, entre los que se encuentra Cplex, y tambien Coin-OR CBC (que viene instalado por defecto con PuLP y también es gratis).

Comment: Gracias :D , encontré muchos modulos interesantes para problemas de PL :D saludos.